# C++ NTP Server implementation

Tags: c++, ntp

I would need to implement my own NTP server or just pick an existing one and integrate it in one application. I have tried to find available source code of NTP servers in C++ but I did not succeed. Could anybody help me?

Kindest regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific C++ implementations, but [the ntp.org distribution](http://www.ntp.org/downloads.html) is free software written in C, and is pretty much as stable as you can get.